# How do I set my product page in Magento in Ascending direction permanently

Tags: products

I am just new to Magento and I need some help as to How do I set my products in Ascending direction permanently through admin. Every time I go into my website t automatically puts the products in Descending order. 
Thank You 
Karryn

Comment: Do you mean sort by alphabetical order?

Comment: I would like them sorted by price highest to lowest in my product page. The lowest products always show first. I would like these to automatically show at the bottom. See my website

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this can help

Go To:

> System > Configuration > In left Sidebar >Catalog > Catalog > Frontend > Product
>   Listing Sort by

Set `Name`

For price to Descending, select price from admin and create a file at location:

> app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php

And copy paste the file from

> app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php

file there:

and in the function :

```
public function getProductCollection()
```

Update the code from :

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
            ->addCategoryFilter($this);
```

To:

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
            ->setOrder('price', 'DESC')
            ->addCategoryFilter($this);
```

This code is from magento 1.9

Comment: Hello I was following your instructions , I got to and in the function :public function getProductCollection() How do I update the code from there?? Sorry I am not experienced at all with this . I am trying to do this myself. Thanks for your help

Comment: Just replace the code to what i shared, that has the line setOrder in the function getProductCollection

Answer (score 1):

Glamorous Hairstyles,you  can managed from admin panel Goto

```
System > Configuration > Catalog>Catalog>Product Listing Sort
```

Here you can select you desire attribute,As you want to selecting Name then select name as default sort attribute.

By default  magento coding its default sort order is Ascending.

```
goto app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
  protected $_direction           = 'asc';
```

Comment: Hello, Thankyou. I want it set at price highest to lowest on the product page. I am not sure in admin how to do this : app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php (where do I go?)

Comment: Is this where I change it. I don't understand HTML..  <reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_top.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
</block>
</reference>

Comment: just add below code toolbar for default sort <action method="setDefaultDirection"><direction>desc</direction></action>

Comment: full code 

 <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"> 
 <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
   <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_top.phtml"> 
   <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
     </block> 
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name>
    </action>
   <action method="setDefaultDirection"><direction>desc</direction></action> 
  </block>
 </block>

Comment: this code means Product listing on root category

Comment: Hello, I tried to do what you said but it's not working. Maybe I missed a space.

Comment: <reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_top.phtml">
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
<action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
<action method="setDefaultDirection"><direction>desc</direction></action> </block> </block>
</block>
</reference>

Comment: The error says XML data is invalid